# Is it possible to implement social sign-in and sign-in with email and password both?

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-oauth, passport.js, social-authentication

Let's suppose user initially signed in website/app using social sign-in (ex: By Google, GitHub etc.).

Is that user will able to login using email and password (same as used for social sign-in) ?

Is it possible ?
If Yes, then how ?

Comment: You do not know the password for the social login, that is the point. After a user logged via the old way you can offer them the option to switch login method by allowing them to e.g. set a username / password and storing those in your db following best practices for password storage. You need to implement that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

When the user initially signed using `social sign-in` (OAUTH), you can just register their information(like email) into your database.

But the password can't be `same as used for social sign-in` because you won't have the user's password through `social sign-in` (OAUTH).

You would either ask them to enter a password when using `social sign-in` or generate a password for them and tell them to keep it.